# Can you run start chromium from regular browser by using puppeteer with browserify?

Tags: webpack, requirejs, browserify, puppeteer

I'm trying to run a Puppeteer script with a buttonclick from a regular browser. Therefor, I packaged my app using browserify so I can use require('puppeteer') in the browser, like we can do with other modules that use require().

I did this by running "browserify main.js -o bundle.js" from the terminal in the relevant directory, like I do with other browserify projects. But with Puppeteer I get the following error when I run the script after bundling:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
at Object.52../helper (bundle.js:8800)
at o (bundle.js:1)
at bundle.js:1
at Object. (bundle.js:11817)
at Object.62../Browser (bundle.js:12161)
at o (bundle.js:1)
at bundle.js:1
at Object.68../BrowserFetcher (bundle.js:14534)
at o (bundle.js:1)
at bundle.js:1
```

Any idea what might be causing this?
Or is this just impossible to do with puppeteer contrary to other modules?

You can find the very short code here:

https://github.com/dutchsparks/browserifypuppeteer

Comment: Puppeteer is launching a whole Chromium for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run Puppeteer in a browser - this package only works inside a node environment. You can setup backend with Puppeteer and send requests to it from a browser.

Comment: "You can setup backend with Puppeteer and send requests to it from a browser."
sounds good, could you elaborate a little on how would one do this?